# How to update z-index values in two related lists 'A,B'(B is sortable items)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, css-selectors

The two list are A, and B. The list B is sortable (drag-drop), each item in list 'B' is related with each item in list 'A' by index !
we set first this css propety to list 'B' items

````
#sortable2 li:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 10!important;
  background-color: rgb(149, 168, 228);

}

#sortable2 li:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 9!important;
  background-color: rgb(69, 223, 31);

}

#sortable2 li:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 8!important;
  background-color: rgb(230, 47, 123);

}  ```
````

when the page is loaded, it dynamically give z-index of each item in
List 'B' to  each item in List 'A'; like this:

**List B: #sortable2 li
List A:#textSegments .jmSeg**

```
for(var i=0;i<=$('#sortable2 li').length; i++){
    
        console.log($('#sortable2 li').eq(i).css('z-index'));
        $('#textSegments .jmSeg').eq(i).css('z-index',$('#sortable2 li').eq(i).css('z-index'));
    }
```

my question is  after resort  List 'B' items  the z-index values in list 'B' change depending on the position of the item(layer). The "top item" of list 'B' set the highest z-index value and the last item gets the lowest z-index value ,
but z-index of  List 'A' no changes.
i tried this code below code to update list A z-index but also no changes

```
 $('#sortable2').sortable({ ........
.....................................
 update: function (event, ui) {
        
        for(var i=0;i<=$('#sortable2 li').length; i++){
    
                    console.log($('#sortable2 li:nth-child('+i+')').css('z-index'));
                    $('#textSegments .jmSeg').eq(i).css('z-index',$('#sortable2 li:nth-child('+i+')').css('z-index'));
                }
```

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hXad.jpg
```

Comment: Hey there :) You can either do it with just CSS or just JS. You don't need both(I think for now) Since you're already looping trough LIST B, you don't need to set `z-index` in CSS, you can do it in JS in that same loop. It would be more dynamic.

Comment: What is your goal with the LIST A here? Why do they need to have same z-index?